# script post message without check login phpbb3

Tags: validation, post, authentication, phpbb3

I have made an script that replaces the `posting.php` in some forums, but without login in, I can post with it... which code I need to add or edit to make that check?

My script only has a form with some inputs and a submit button, and some lines of phpbb3 to integrate it with theme, and to use the `submit_post` function.

But I dont know how to restrict the script to logged users....

I have tried to read posting.php, but nothing was solved...

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My assumption is that you already have access to the `$users` object from PHPBB.

Since the first user in the system is `Anonymous` (and PHPBB uses this as the [guest account](https://www.phpbb.com/support/documentation/3.0/adminguide/acp_users.php)), you can check if that is the user currently being used.

```
if ($user->data['username'] == 'Anonymous')
{
    echo 'Please login!';
}
else
{
    // Your existing code
}
```